# Re-Adding Fragment Programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm building an application that uses nested fragments. The first layer of fragments is an animated menu where one fragment is the menu and the other is the content.  Some of the content fragments will also contain fragments (child fragments). I want to disable the back button from popping the fragment stack on the first layer of fragments however.

I have successfully delegated the back button to work with the child fragments. For the top level fragments I want to reuse them if they have been created so I save the fragments to a hash and when a new fragment is added I just remove() the current fragment then do a replace() with the new fragment so the view is updated. I never call addToBackStack.  However when trying to navigate back to a previously created fragment (that is saved in the hash) I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
```

But only when getChildFragmentManager() is called from re-added nested fragments.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why.  Any suggestion?

Comment: what is your code for readding the fragment ?